# SQL - Update Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have the following tables:

Events(IDEvent, IDBracelet, IDSensor, DateTime, TypeofEvent);
Sensor(IDSensor, IDArea);
Days_Areas(IDFestivalDay, IDBracelet, IDArea).

I've been trying to do an update on events, when a bracelet does not have permission to be in a certain area.
I've done the following so far, it works for every scenario, except for when I insert a correct and a wrong event at the same time.

```
update Events
set TypeofEvent='red'
from inserted i,Events e
where i.IDEvent=e.IDEvent and exits (select * from inserted i join Days_Areas a on i.IDBracelet=a.IDBracelet join
 Sensor s on s.IDSensor=i.IDSensor where a.IDArea <> s.IDArea);
```

This trigger is an after insert, update.
Is there anyone who can tell me where is the problem?

EDIT: I have another question about this trigger.
When I try to insert at the same time an event where the same bracelet passes by one sensor where it has permission and passes by another where it doesn't have permission, the correct event still changes to red.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update Events
set TypeofEvent='red'
from inserted i
INNER JOIN Events e
    ON i.IDEvent=e.IDEvent 
INNER join Days_Areas a 
    on i.IDBracelet=a.IDBracelet
INNER join Sensor s 
    on s.IDSensor=i.IDSensor 
where a.IDArea <> s.IDArea
```